# cURL Bash save response body to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I've been create curl in bash and here i want save to a file as log with calling function `save_log()` , but when i opened the txt file it's just show me **execute at** only, while **Header Code** and **Response Body** are blank (empty)

here is my script :

```
SECRET_KEY='lolz'
FILE_NAME="test.txt"


function save_log()
{
  printf '%s\n' \
    "Header Code  : $1" \
    "Executed at  : $(date)" \
    "Response Body  : $2" \
    "====================================================================================================="$'\r\n\n'  >> output.log
}

# while IFS= read -r line; do
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
    do
      HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -L -w "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -H "X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook" -H 'X-Gitlab-Token: '$SECRET_KEY --insecure $line 2>&1) &
      HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g') &
      HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://') &
      echo $HTTP_RESPONSE
      save_log "$HTTP_STATUS" "$HTTP_BODY" &
done < $FILE_NAME
```

and here is the output

```
    Header Code  : 
    Executed at  : Mon Jul 1 07:01:40 WIB 2019
    Response Body  : 
    =====================================================================================================
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the & from your bash statements? They are being ran in the background. I can only assume the variables to which you are assigning the output will be empty because of this.

Comment: Were you able to test & validate? If you did so with success, please accept the answer or comment it to further improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the **control operator** `&` that forces your commands to be ran in the background and asynchronously of your own script control flow.

This will cause your `save_log()` function to be called with no arguments (because they we're in background and probably didn't even finished when you called `save_log()`).

I tested and it works (I didn't know which URLs you had on your FILE_NAME, so I just added some random URLs):

```
SECRET_KEY='lolz'
FILE_NAME="test.txt"


function save_log()
{
  printf '%s\n' \
    "Header Code  : $1" \
    "Executed at  : $(date)" \
    "Response Body  : $2" \
    "====================================================================================================="$'\r\n\n'  >> output.log
}

# while IFS= read -r line; do
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; 
    do
      HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -L -w "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -H "X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook" -H 'X-Gitlab-Token: '$SECRET_KEY --insecure $line 2>&1)
      HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
      HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
      echo $HTTP_RESPONSE
      save_log "$HTTP_STATUS" "$HTTP_BODY"
done < $FILE_NAME
```

Output:

```
Header Code  : 200
Executed at  : Sun Jun 30 18:05:12 UTC 2019
Response Body  : <!DOCTYPE html> (...)
```